# How to add payload to a posted MQTT topic?

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I am experimenting with `node-red`, connecting it to my MQTT broker.

The input (listening to a topic) works fine.

I also would like to send to a topic some payload ipon some triggers. In the example below, this would be on a query to a webservice:

[image]

**I did not have a place to add the payload to the published message, where can I set it up?**

The documentation mentions in the *inputs* section:

> `payload`
>
> most users prefer simple text payloads, but binary buffers can also be
>   published.

and later

> `msg.payload` is used as the payload of the published message. If it
>   contains an Object it will be converted to a JSON string before being
>   sent. If it contains a binary Buffer the message will be published
>   as-is.

I tried to add `{msg: {payload: 'on'}}` or `{payload: 'on'}` in *node settings -> inputs* but the payload is not carried to the MQTT, which hows an incoming `cmnd/home/room1/switch1/power {}`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The payload comes from the incoming message. It does not make sense to define a static payload in the `MQTT-out` node.

The entry in the `node-settings` is just a mouse over label for the input, since nodes can only have 1 input it's not that useful, it's more for when nodes have multiple outputs to make it easier to identify which output is which.

In the case you have posted a screen shot ofit will take the `msg.payload` output from the `http-in` node, which would be the body of a HTTP POST.

If want to add a static payload to be published then the easiest way is to add a `change` node between the `http-in` and `mqtt-out` node.

e.g. to set the payload to "foo"

[image]

You can set JSON objects by selecting the type from the drop down on the left hand end of the `to` field.

Comment: Sorry but I do not really understand. My example was to have a trigger (a http call but it could have been anything) which would trigger a message sent to MQTT (via an `MQTT-out` node ( which *Connects to a MQTT broker and publishes messages*)). I need to send a static payload to MQTT, wouldn't that be done via an `MQTT-out` node?

Comment: OK, I got it (somehow) - I need to add a `change` node in order to tell `mqtt-out`about its payload? (If so it is strange the payload is not defined directly on the `mqtt-out` node)

Comment: No, the node expects to be passed a payload to publish, not just publish the same message over and over. Most (all) Node-RED output nodes work this way

Comment: Thank you - I understand. A static payload makes sense for switches and I thought that I would have one `MQTT-out` per switch. If I understand correctly, I will have one for all the switches, with a payload defined upstream (= depending on the path which led to the message)

Comment: You can also leave the topic blank in the `mqtt-out` node and pass that in via the incoming `msg` as well